# Shopify multiple Shipping methods?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How do you set 2 shipping methods in Shopify? UK has 2 popular shipping methods:
1st class - you pay more and item arrives that day.
2nd class - cheaper, item arrives between 2-3 days.
I want to setting both options, giving the customer opportunity to choose which option they want.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017 you need to be on Shopify Advanced or Shopify Plus in order to get more than just zone shipping outside of the US or Canada.

Either of those plans would allow you to integrate or create an app to offer the shipping methods you want.